# How to speed up the calculation of recurrence formula?

Tags: performance-tuning, code-request

I have a recurrence formula. How to quickly solve P[1] to p[49]?

```
p[0] = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 50}][[1]];
p[i_] := Map[
  RotationTransform[-VectorAngle[{1, 0}, 
     p[i - 1][[Mod[i + 1, 50]]] - p[i - 1][[Mod[i, 50]]]], 
   p[i - 1][[Mod[i, 50]]]], p[i - 1]]
p[1]
```

Table method is very time-consuming. How to speed up the calculation?

```
Table[p[i], {i, 1, 49, 1}]
```

Comment: [Memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) is the trick.

Comment: @Roman: Can you show me the code?

Comment: You should use `Mod[i,5,1]` and `Mod[i + 1, 5,1]`. Otherwise you get `0` indices.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: You're right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

Also, keep in mind that Mathematica uses 1-indexing, so the modulus needs to be calculated with [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Modulo_with_offset) 1 (please check if I got it correct):

```
Clear[p];
p[0] = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 50}][[1]];
p[i_] := p[i] =
  Map[RotationTransform[-VectorAngle[{1, 0}, 
    p[i - 1][[Mod[i + 1, 5, 1]]] - p[i - 1][[Mod[i, 5, 1]]]], 
    p[i - 1][[Mod[i, 5, 1]]]], p[i - 1]]
```

Comment: Yes, much faster than before.